# Connection R with odbc using ini -fle

Tags: r, odbc, dbi

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database from within R using odbc. If I write the connection information it works well, however, if I put the same information in a odbc.ini file, I get an error.

Here is the code that works

```
library(DBI)
   con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                         Driver   = "MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver",
                         Server   = "localhost",
                         UID      = "myname",
                         PWD      = "mypassword",
                         Database = "vgr",
                         encoding = "latin1",
                         Port     = 3306)
```

And here the code that doesn't work

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 'MySQL')
```

The error is (it looks like dbConnect doesn't find the information):

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: IM002: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

This is in my odbc.ini either in the working directory or where Windows saves it ODBC.ini file.

```
[MySQL]
Driver   = MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver
Server   = localhost
UID      = myname
PWD      = mypassword
Database = vgr
encoding = latin1
Port     = 3306
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers
Renger

Comment: Matching that `odbc.ini` file should be an entry in `odbcinst.ini` that defines `[MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver]`. Assuming this in windows, is there a reason you're using `ini` files and not windows' main ODBC configuration interface?

Comment: Hi, the file is there with the right drivers mentioned. I solved it now as follows:
- I have a text file with my UID and PWD which I read with readr.
- Then in my function, I read this file and insert the values in the connection.
This is for a project with multiple users. The idea is that everybody has a different username and password. The only thing they now have to do is write the text file with the username and their password.